# Prevent Binding Loop with TextChanged-Event

Tags: data-binding, maui

I have an Entry with implemented TextChanged-Event in XAML of my .NET MAUI App.

I wanted to prevent an empty Entry-Text and set „0“ instead when it‘s empty.

So, in TextChanged-Event I assigned my .Text to „0“ in case of string.IsNullOrEmptyCharacter(e.NewCalue). But now, in my model the bound value property is hit in Debugger in an endless-loop.

How would I solve this? Still wanted to make sure that the Text is updated by both, changes in the model as well the model, when Text is chanted/deleted.

How should I do this?

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: `But now, in my model the bound value property is hit in Debugger in an endless-loop.` Could you please elaborate on your problem? What's the `an endless-loop`?

Comment: All your problems can be probably solved in less than a minute, if we actually see the code. And without seeing it, it is "endless loop" of guessing what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not posted your code, I'll give a generic answer.

The infinite loop occurs because your text-changed method is changing the value, thus firing text-changed again.

The solution is to make sure you "do nothing" if text-changed fires due to your programmatic change.

One way to do this, is to "do nothing", if your logic doesn't actually cause a change:

```cs
... MyTextChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    string alteredNewValue = newValue;

    ... // Logic that examines newValue, MAYBE comes up with a different value.

    // Avoids infinite loop, in case above logic tries to set same value again
    if (alteredNewValue == newValue)
        return;   // DON'T set the property again!

    // CAUTION: POTENTIAL INFINITE LOOP.
    MyTextProperty = alteredNewValue;
}
```

---

**ANOTHER POSSIBLE FIX**

Maybe there is a lurking issue if the property is set again during the TextChanged handler. If so, a simpler fix is to **queue** the property setting, so it happens after Maui has completed its changed processing:

```cs
...
Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => MyTextProperty = alteredNewValue);
```

Comment: If `MyTextProperty` is observable (and it must be, because it's being bound to by the `Entry` control), then it won't raise the `PropertyChanged` event if the current value and the new value are the same. We need to see the relevant code in order to examine the problem.

Comment: I see your point, BUT I've experienced the exact case being discussed, at least in Xamarin.Forms. For example, If `newValue` was `string.Empty`, and the logic changes that to `"NothingToSeeHere"`, then the first call to MyTextChanged will have `newValue = string.Empty`, and will set `alteredNewValue = "NothingToSeeHere"`. It will set the property to "NothingToSeeHere". This fires a second text changed with oldValue=string.Empty and newValue="NothingToSeeHere". My code ensures that MyTextProperty is not set a second time. In the case I am thinking of, perhaps the setter didn't protect itself.

Comment: Anyway, I've seen that infinite loop, even when the new value was repeatedly the same. Unfortunately I don't recall the exact details, but it did involve a TextChanged handler like this. Or perhaps it was the corresponding method override, not the handler, that got fired repeatedly. (Even though, as you say, that "shouldn't" happen.) [My memory claims that] It wasn't just a property setter; there was a method responding to the change. FWIW, in case it turns out there is some edge condition that is bugged.

Comment: I've added an alternative fix, to cover the possibility that there is a subtle bug if set the new value too early. TBD whether this is relevant for Maui, or just deals with an old XForms bug.

Comment: The hint with 

```// Avoids infinite loop, in case above logic tries to set same value again
    if (alteredNewValue == newValue)
        return;   // DON'T set the property again!
```

helped and prevented the endless-loop here. Marked it as answer.

I also was re-thinking it from a user perspective. In case the Entry.Text was empty, I wanted to set it to "0" instead. But, for a user this meant that she wasn't able to delete the text and enter a number instead, which was strange in the end from a usability standpoint. Or what do you think?

Comment: Don't set to "0" as long as Entry has focus. You could set to 0 if not focused.  I think there is an event when loses focus.